# How to write a trigger to abort delete in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-delete

I read this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20180330233216/http://www.brokenbuild.com/blog/2006/08/15/mysql-triggers-how-do-you-abort-an-insert-update-or-delete-with-a-trigger/) but it seems not work for delete. I got this error when tried to create a trigger:

> Executing SQL script in server
>
> ERROR: Error 1363: There is no NEW row in on DELETE trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeviceCatalog_PreventDeletion 
BEFORE DELETE on DeviceCatalog
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE dummy INT;

    IF old.id = 1 or old.id =2 THEN
        SELECT * FROM DeviceCatalog WHERE DeviceCatalog.id=NEW.id;
    END IF;
END;
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 4 succeeded, 1 failed

Comment: NEW.fieldname exists when you insert or update a record; when you delete nothing new is coming to database!!! The error is clear: you can't use NEW.id because NEW is not permitted in a DELETE trigger

Comment: According to the linked article the select statatement should fail - your select statement reads like a real one and not like the `select into dummy` from the article which is intended to fail.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try something like this -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE DELETE
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF OLD.id = 1 THEN -- Abort when trying to remove this record
    CALL cannot_delete_error; -- raise an error to prevent deleting from the table
  END IF;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: MySQL has added the SIGNAL command to raise errors. I think it was added after this answer. If anyone is interested: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

Comment: Great addition @MathewFoscarini, I've just re-answered the question using Devart's answer and the SIGNAL command you suggested.

Answer (score 21):

Improving @Devart's (accepted) answer with @MathewFoscarini's comment about [MySQL SIGNAL Command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html), instead of raising an error by calling an inexistent procedure you could signal your custom error message.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER DeviceCatalog_PreventDeletion
BEFORE DELETE ON DeviceCatalog
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  IF old.id IN (1,2) THEN -- Will only abort deletion for specified IDs
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' -- "unhandled user-defined exception"
      -- Here comes your custom error message that will be returned by MySQL
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This record is sacred! You are not allowed to remove it!!';
  END IF;

END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The SQLSTATE 45000 was chosen as [MySQL's Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) suggests:

> To signal a generic SQLSTATE value, use '45000', which means “unhandled user-defined exception.”

This way your custom message will be shown to the user whenever it tries to delete records ID `1` or `2`. Also, if no records should be deleted from the table, you could just remove the `IF .. THEN` and `END IF;` lines. This would prevent **ANY** records from being deleted on the table.

Comment: i can't get this to work with jdbc connector. It throws an error:  createSQLException  unknown table in a where clause.

Comment: Can you clarify the point about deleting no records from the table? If I run a single delete query for multiple rows, but only one row triggers the condition, will the other rows be deleted?

Answer (score 6):

Well, the error messages tells you quite clearly: in a DELETE trigger there is no NEW.

- In an INSERT trigger you can access the new values with NEW..
- In an UPDATE trigger you can access the new values with NEW., the old ones with - you guessed it - OLD.
- In a DELETE trigger you can acces the old values with OLD..

It simply makes no sense to have NEW in a DELETE, just as OLD in an INSERT makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says: There is no NEW variable on delete.

you can use new.id only on insert and update. Use old.id instead.

```
SELECT * FROM DeviceCatalog WHERE DeviceCatalog.id=old.id;
```