# MySQL: how to prevent deletion?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

Once a record is entered in a particular table, I think I don't ever want it to be deleted. The records are there to keep track of things for historical purposes. I'm using MySQL, InnoDB. Is there any way I can protect that table from accidental deletes by the application layer? If so, is this a good approach?

Comment: cf. https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/159670

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a trigger to abort delete in MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595714/how-to-write-a-trigger-to-abort-delete-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other option is switch to the [ARCHIVE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/archive-storage-engine.html) engine for historical tables.

This will prevent any DELETE or UPDATE actions on the table, and compress the data. One (major) downside to this approach is that you cannot index the columns on the table.

Comment: What does it mean to me if columns cannot be indexed? Is it OK to mix InnoDB and Archive?

Comment: By the way, I used InnoDB so I can enforce referential integrity. What happens to that when I use Archive?

Comment: Archive has no "row cache." What does this mean to me? Also, it says "note that lots of SELECT statements during insertion can deteriorate the compression, unless only bulk or delayed inserts are used" -- what potential problems might this cause me?

Comment: You lose Foreign Key support, but I made the answer in response to this part of the question: "I don't ever want it to be deleted". Not having indexes on a large table could slow the SELECT queries down, which is why it's better to run any analytical queries on a slave.

Comment: Do you think using Archive is worth losing referential integrity? How do I set up running queries on a slave?

Answer (score 4):

If you can set the permission for your user(s), don't give the delete permission. There're situations where this practice is a "must be" like the tables for statistics purpose. Thus, if your table is used to achieve one of this goal, it's a good approach.

Comment: I can do this for a specific table? Does this require configuring something on the server? Meaning, every time I install this application, I would need to keep doing this? What if I forget?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie As far as I know, you can't. Usually you need to configure it on the server. Moreover you have to do this everytime and if you forgot it, the user(s) will be able to delete the row(s).

Answer (score 2):

I use a trigger that detects the deletion and does some illegal stuff so the whole operation fails. For example like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER protect_delete before delete ON protected_table 
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE non_existing_table SET non_existing_column=1;
```

So when someone will attempt a delete operation - the whole statement will fail. You also might use better names for non_existing_column and non_existing_table.

E.g it is possible to obtain an error message like this:

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'database.delete_restricted_on_tableX'
>   doesn't exist

EDIT: also it is possible to create even better fail messages, please check here http://www.brokenbuild.com/blog/2006/08/15/mysql-triggers-how-do-you-abort-an-insert-update-or-delete-with-a-trigger/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement this logic in your application layer and insert a column where you put a no-delete flag.

Another idea would be to exclude the delete access for the db user

Comment: I'm trying to protect the table from the application layer. I won't implement anything to delete in this table. However, I want to make sure the table can defend itself no matter what (for example, someone else implements some logic to delete in this table later on -- or someone uses phpMyAdmin and tries to delete something in that table).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to write a trigger that detects the deletion, then reinserts the record, but there may be some issues with that, so you can also just add a foreign key constraint that will prevent the deletion.

For some discussions on this you can look at: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2011/10/mysql-hacks-preventing-deletion-of.html.

Comment: Reinserting the record means it would lose the original auto-increment PK it has, right? How does your FK constraint solution work?

Comment: I read the link you provided. The FK constraint solution seems hackish. What do you think?

Comment: Any of these approach are a bit hackish.  Preventing people from being able to delete is the correct idea, but you can insert into an auto-increment column as long as it doesn't violate uniqueness.