# prevent delete * from table unless primary key specified

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, amazon-aurora

I want to prevent user from using deleting * from table unless primary key specified, one of our team member accendently used "delete * from table_name" i want to prevent such scenarios in future.

Comment: What and slow down every delete on every table? No proper backups is the solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595714/how-to-write-a-trigger-to-abort-delete-in-mysql

Comment: Do not use a trigger. e4c5 is correct and you need proper backups and sensible database access security.

Comment: Revoke delete privileges and create a stored proc to delete from the table.. trigger cant be used to check if the WHERE is been used in the DELETE query

Answer (score 0):

Would [safe updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates) be viable for you? This is an option you can enable on the command line, in the option file or set a variable in SQL code that prevents updates and deletes without a `where` clause that includes the key columns defining the rows to change.

In MySQL Workbench there is a setting in `Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Safe Updates (rejects UPDATEs and DELETEs with no restriction)`. I believe this is even on by default.