# Oracle PL/SQL: Prevent delete * from table unless primary key specified

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

In Oracle PL/SQL language, I would like to prevent user from using deleting * from table unless primary key specified.

How could I achieve this?

I've just found a similar question, but in a different language: [prevent delete * from table unless primary key specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892686/prevent-delete-from-table-unless-primary-key-specified)

Could you please help me to find a solution in Oracle PL/SQL language?

EDIT:

```
SELECT * FROM V$VERSION;

BANNER,CON_ID
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production,0
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production,0
CORE    12.1.0.2.0  Production,0
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production,0
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production,0
```

Comment: As the given solution (in comments) on that question you linked, you have to do this in triggers. To make it usable for all tables, you would have to create a function that receives the table name and look into the dictionary to see what are the primary keys columns and with it check if they were filled.

Comment: What's the structure of the primary key in your table? Is it just and auto-increment integer field?

Comment: The trigger has to be general, and appliable to any table.

Comment: How will you delete all employees from a department (for example)? Don't you just want to restrict `delete` without `where` clauses, or without `where` clauses referencing indexed columns?

Comment: If you want to restrict someone from deleting records you should revoke the privilege; you can then create an API in PL/SQL which allows them to perform the deletes you want to allow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone observed in the referenced thread, this requirement amounts to *I want to slow down every deletion executed in my database*. Not to mention that sometimes bulk deletions are necessary.

This is a classic example of a trying to apply a technical fix to what is a political situation, a failure of process. I once knew a developer who initiated a delete of a *massive* (multi-million row) table because they didn't know how to scope variables in PL/SQL. But it would be wrong to penalize the entire development team because of one person's silly mistake.

The correct solution is to implement one or both of these:

- make sure your developers (or any user with raw SQL access) understand how to write proper SQL
- withdraw DELETE privileges from people who can't be trusted with them
- have decent back-ups so it doesn't matter whether somebody deletes all the records

Answer (score 1):

not sure, but a delete will fail if a constraint is violated, so I'd look to see if you can create a constraint that will be violated (e.g. foreign key constraint where child record exists that must be deleted first).

Comment: But that won't change the behavior of the delete itself. A user could zap all the child records then delete all the parent records.

Comment: @apc If OP's users have that much access to the DB that they don't want, they're in trouble.