# msql 5.0 BEFORE DELETE TRIGGER - CANCEL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a MySQL 5.0 server.   I want to build a BEFORE DELETE TRIGGER that will ignore a delete statement if a condition exists.

I do not need to return a message if the DELETE fails the condition.

All the examples I have found use SIGNAL SQLSTATE to throw an error.
Sound great, only MySQL 5.0 does not support SIGNAL SQLSTATE.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`myname`@`%` 
TRIGGER  `tbtimecard_BDEL` 
BEFORE DELETE ON  `tbtimecard`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if date(old.dt_of_entry) <> curdate() then
        delete from `rhi_sap`.`tbtimecard` where id = 0;

    END IF;
END$$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a trigger to abort delete in MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595714/how-to-write-a-trigger-to-abort-delete-in-mysql)

Comment: I'm not sure this approach can even work, as the trigger is operating on the same table scoped by the trigger.

Comment: ^^ Check the hack of calling an undefined procedure to trigger error in the above link.

Comment: You're using a version of MySQL released in 2005. I recommend you just upgrade. Not only do you need at least this feature that is provided by newer versions, but the version you're using has critical security bugs.

Comment: According to documention, I found on MySQL 5.0, the trigger cannot use the CALL statement.

Comment: Upgrading is a not an option... I wish it was.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen -  I understand....   What approach would you use?   All I need to do is ignore the delete if the condition exists.    I have no requirement to return a message.

Comment: To Madhur's statement, the solution you gave, uses the CALL statement.   MySQL 5.0  does not allow the use of a CALL in a trigger.

Comment: @Gene ohho..anyways, the general idea in that solution is to do something which causes the trigger to fail. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/703505/2469308) and other answers on that question..

Comment: Exactly.. `SELECT non_existing_function('error description for debugging') INTO @nirvana;`

Comment: It's not perfect, but it works.   Throws an error back...  I was hoping for no message..   Under the circumstances, I will call it a win.    
I do realize running on such an old version of MySQL is not ideal, but that is not my decision to upgrade.